# Why does the part after "que" need to be expressed in inversion?

Tags: grammaire, inversion

> « Tu as dû bien t'en tirer, vu le souvenir **qu'en ont gardé les hommes du président**. »

Translation:

> "You must have pulled out of the situation just fine, considering how the President’s men remembered it."

The construction of this sentence has me stumped. I’d like to know why the part after the "**que**" needs to be in inversion.

Also, am I correct in assuming that the second "**en**" refers to "(le souvenir) **de la situation**", and that the "**as dû**" means "**must have** {an informed guess}" rather than "**had to** {an obligation}"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Les 6 formes sont correctes:**

en : pronom pour *de la situation* accolé au pronom relatif que (pour souvenir), **avec inversion** dans la relative

> Tu as dû bien t'en tirer, vu le souvenir qu'en ont gardé les hommes du
>   président.

*de la situation* accolé à *souvenir*, **avec inversion** dans la relative

> Tu as dû bien t'en tirer, vu le souvenir de la situation qu'ont gardé
>   les hommes du président.

*de la situation* accolé à *souvenir*, **sans inversion** dans la relative

> Tu as dû bien t'en tirer, vu le souvenir de la situation que les
>   hommes du président ont gardé.

*de la situation* repoussé à la fin, **avec inversion** dans la relative

> Tu as dû bien t'en tirer, vu le souvenir qu'ont gardé les hommes du
>   président de la situation.

*de la situation* repoussé à la fin, **sans inversion** dans la relative

> Tu as dû bien t'en tirer, vu le souvenir que les hommes du président
>   ont gardé de la situation.

en : pronom pour *de la situation* repoussé dans la relative, **sans inversion**

> Tu as dû bien t'en tirer, vu le souvenir que les hommes du président
>   en ont gardé.

**Inversion**

c'est possible avec une **relative** qui a un **sujet qui n'est pas un pronom**

> La pomme que je mange => pas d'inversion possible.
>
> La pomme que Jean mange ou La pomme que mange Jean.

Comment: Merci pour une explication très approfondie. Je me demande si les deux formes suivantes sont également correctes ? « Tu as dû bien t'en tirer, vu le souvenir **de la situation** que les hommes du président ont gardé. » et « Tu as dû bien t'en tirer, vu le souvenir que les hommes du président ont gardé **de la situation**. »

Comment: @pourraitpuet-etre - ces 2 formes sont aussi exactes. Je les ai ajoutées.

Answer (score 2):

L'inversion n'est pas obligatoire, on pourrait tout aussi bien dire :

> Tu as dû bien t'en tirer, vu le souvenir que les hommes du président en ont gardé.